# C++ call function with string as parameter

Tags: c++, maps

Lets say I have several functions like `function1()`, `function2()`, ....., `function1000()`
and I am getting a string in a function lets say `call_function(string function_name)`.
Now I need to execute function based on `function_name`.

I searched for solutions and found I can use maps.

Is there any easy way to create a map for lets say 1000 `keys(string type)` and respective functions ?
eg: `call_function(function541)` then it should execute `function541()`;

Comment: you can use std::function() for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map to function pointers for this stuff

```
void func1(const char *args)
{
     //....
}

void func2(const char *args)
{
     //....
}

typedef void (*function) (const char *args);

//......

std::map<std::string, function> func_map;

func_map.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("func1", func1));
func_map.insert(std::pair<std::string, function>("func2", func2));

func_map["func1"]("arg1 arg2 arg3"); // Here is the func1 call
```

Comment: First, that's not "easy". Second, why function pointers and not `std::function`? Third, why `char*`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any easy way to create a map for lets say 1000 `keys(string type)` and respective functions ?
>
> eg: `call_function(function541)`
>   then it should execute `function541()`;

No, there is no easy way, because **C++ does not have reflection**. Function names only exist for the compiler. At run-time, there is no relationship between a function called `function541` in your source code and the string `"function541"` existing in memory while the program is being executed.

Each and any of such links must be established manually:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> map;
// ...
map["function541"] = function541;
```

Of course, you can still automate such a task with code generation. Functions with mechanical names like this don't look like manually written C++ code anyway. That is, you can write a script in some other language that creates the C++ code to add the thousand functions to the map, perhaps as some kind of pre-build step.

Still, from a run-time point of view, there's no automation whatsoever.

Comment: Firts of all `char *` is the example, secondly I am an old fashion guy who did not like the beast in which C++ transformed after 11 standard. Now it is better to chose from more natural languages C or C# (sorry, I do not like Java from its very begining).

Comment: @Mykola: Examples should not teach broken code. I am old-fashioned, too, but `char*` is still wrong on many levels. For example, you cannot even pass a string literal to such a function without a compiler warning; the invalidity of the conversion from string literals to non-const `char*` predates C++98. Hardly a C++11 aspect. What C, Java and C# have to do with this is beyond me. Note that `char*` would be likewise wrong in C; even there it should be `char const*`.

Comment: Tested `char *` with GCC 5, MVC 13, no any errors or warnings.

Comment: @Mykola: I don't know what you tested, but a conversion from a `char const` array to a `char*` is not legal. Why would it be legal? It doesn't make sense. That's why all compilers I know are able to treat this as a warning or an error (the latter is preferable). Sorry to be blunt, but a simple Google search for "char* deprecated conversion" would have been faster than conducting this entire conversation, and 420 000 results can explain the issue much better than a tiny comment box.

Comment: I write down this code

using namespace std;
map<string, void()> mymap;

void create_map(string strName,int i){

 mymap[strName] = myfunct10;
}

void myfunct10(){
    cout<<"its myfunct10"<<endl;
}

but still my code is not working. What is wrong ?

Comment: @techy That does not look correct. It should be `std::function<void()>`, not just `void()`. The `i` argument is not used. And "not working" is not a very precise error description! :)